# C# HttpListener - 503 Not Available (2 Apps, 2 Prefixes)

Tags: c#, httplistener

I tried the solutions from other threads (specifically the top to similar questions), but I'm obviously missing something or not understanding.

So I have two applications

> App1 - with HttpListener - listening on prefix http://+:8083/app1/
>
> App2 with HttpListener - listening on prefix http://+:8083/app2/

Problem:
When I start App1 first, and then App2, App2 gives me a 503 Not Available.

When I start App2 first, and then App1, both Apps respond 200 OK.

I have verified the url registration via netsh http show urlacl. See output below.

And I have verified that the apps add the correct listener prefixes.

```
>  Reserved URL            : http://+:8083/app1/
>  User: domain\user1
>  Listen: Yes
>  Delegate: No
>  SDDL: D:(A;;GX;;;S-1-5-21-599267633-1814252160-3967499608-1001)

>  Reserved URL            : http://+:8083/app2/
>  User: domain\user1
>  Listen: Yes
>  Delegate: No
>  SDDL: D:(A;;GX;;;S-1-5-21-599267633-1814252160-3967499608-1001)
```

Please help :-)

Comment: I have also tried:
1. setting user to "everyone"
2. included a manifest file to have my service start up with administrator privileges (didn't seem viable solution, but tried anyway). 

It does seem related to the specific application, but the principles for both are the same (same base code as well)

Comment: My best guess is this was, somehow, windows related.
After a number of restarts the problem seems to have resolved itself.

Comment: This issue appeared again. Still not sure how to specifically resolve it. Any thoughts would be appreciated.

Comment: Worked around this for now by registering different services / apps on different ports. However, to my knowledge, should be able to have a unique url/prefix on the same port.